# RewriteRule not working inside FilesMatch

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to do some PHP validation when loading a file to decide if I can show it or not to the user. I need to use PHP because I need to check if the user is logged-in. To do that I added

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads(/(custom_folder)/.*\.\w+)$ index.php?a_parameter=$1 [QSA,L]
```

to my .htaccess. Then each time a user tries to view a file in `/wp-content/uploads/custom_folder/` I check if the `a_parameter` is defined and I do the validation.

That works fine, but now I want to do this validation only for `.htm` and `.html` files. To do that I tried adding

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html)$">
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads(/(custom_folder)/.*\.\w+)$ index.php?a_parameter=$1 [QSA,L]
</FilesMatch>
```

but it's not working.

To give more context, I'm trying to do this in WordPress' .htaccess, so this is the complete .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /_wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /_wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /_wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html)$">
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads(/(custom_folder)/.*\.\w+)$ index.php?a_parameter=$1 [QSA,L]
</FilesMatch>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /_wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my approach. Instead of using `FilesMatch` I changed the regular expression to target files ending in `.htm`, `.html`, and directories. Given the characteristics of the project I'm working on, I can assume that an empty directory will have either an `index.htm` or `index.html`, so this works for me. If it's a directory then I try to find for the index file in the PHP.

```
^wp-content/uploads/custom_folder/((?:.*\/)|.*\.(?:html|htm))$ index.php?relative_path=$1 [QSA,L]
```